# PBEwithMD5andDES on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cryptography

I've tried different ways of encrypting a string with PBEwithMD5andDES, I implemented this with Bouncy Castle but its seems that is nor working since it returns a different string compared to the Java version, all params are the same (password, salt and iteration number)in both versions (C# and Java).

```
    private IBufferedCipher makePbeCipherWithParam(
        string algorithm,
        bool forEncryption,
        char[] password,
        byte[] salt,
        int iterationCount)
    {

        Asn1Encodable algParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateAlgorithmParameters(
            algorithm, salt, iterationCount);
        ICipherParameters cipherParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateCipherParameters(
            algorithm, password, algParams);

        IBufferedCipher cipher = (IBufferedCipher)PbeUtilities.CreateEngine(algorithm);
        cipher.Init(forEncryption, cipherParams);

        return cipher;
    }


    public string StringToPBEWithMD5AndDES(string rawString) {

        char[] password = "APASSWORD".ToCharArray();
        byte[] salt = { .... };


        IBufferedCipher cEnc = makePbeCipherWithParam(
            "PBEwithMD5andDES-CBC",
            true,
            password,
            salt,
            1024);



        byte[] encBytes = cEnc.DoFinal(Hex.Decode(rawString));
        string encodedUser = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encBytes, 0, encBytes.Length);//encBytes.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine("Encoded user from StringToPBEWithMD5AndDES: " + encodedUser);
        return encodedUser;
    }
```

this is the java version I'm trying to replicate

```
public class Utils {
private Cipher ecipher;


public Utils() {

    String passPhrase = "PASSWORD";

    byte[] salt = { ...};

    int iterationCount = 1024;

    try {

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt,iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeySpecException");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchPaddingException");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeyException");
    }
}

public String encrypt(String str) {
    try {
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(enc), "UTF-8");
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly is the problem you encounter? what is the expected output?

Comment: I tried to replicate java's version of PBEwithMD5andDES but I'm not getting the same results between javas version and mine with c# for windows phone, although I get an, lets say, valid output, I'm not able to replicate the same results as in java which I updated in the original answer

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?